# Haskell prime number generator according to bits for very large numbers

Tags: rsa, primes, haskell, primality-test

I just got into haskell. 
I'm trying to write a prime number generator that would return me a prime number depending on the number of bits I give it. Do I use some sort of Sieve of Eratosthenes? Would this be the quickest way? Currently, I already have a prime number checker for Miller-Rabin. Is there a correct way and a wrong way to do this? Also, I want to be able to generate large numbers very quickly.

Ex. generate a prime number that is of 32 bits

```
genp 32
```

Code so far.

```
import System.IO
import System.Random
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import Control.Arrow


primesTo100 = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]

powerMod :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> a -> b -> a
powerMod m _ 0 =  1
powerMod m x n | n > 0 = join (flip f (n - 1)) x `rem` m where
  f _ 0 y = y
  f a d y = g a d where
    g b i | even i    = g (b*b `rem` m) (i `quot` 2)
          | otherwise = f b (i-1) (b*y `rem` m)

witns :: (Num a, Ord a, Random a) => Int -> a -> IO [a]
witns x y = do
     g <- newStdGen 
     let r = [9080191, 4759123141, 2152302898747, 3474749600383, 341550071728321]
         fs = [[31,73],[2,7,61],[2,3,5,7,11],[2,3,5,7,11,13],[2,3,5,7,11,13,17]]
     if  y >= 341550071728321
      then return $ take x $ randomRs (2,y-1) g
       else return $ snd.head.dropWhile ((<= y).fst) $ zip r fs

isMillerRabinPrime :: Integer -> IO Bool
isMillerRabinPrime n | n `elem` primesTo100 = return True
                     | otherwise = do
    let pn = pred n
        e = uncurry (++) . second(take 1) . span even . iterate (`div` 2) $ pn
        try = return . all (\a -> let c = map (powerMod n a) e in
                                  pn `elem` c || last c == 1)
    witns 100 n >>= try



type Prime = Integer

isProbablyPrime :: Prime -> Bool
isProbablyPrime n = isMillerRabinPrime n

pickFirstFrom :: Integer -> Prime
pickFirstFrom n = head $ filter isProbablyPrime [n..]

numBits = 1024
constantStdGen = mkStdGen 1234567 -- a random number

randomByBits n = fst $ randomR (2^(n-1), 2^n-1) constantStdGen

answer = pickFirstFrom (randomByBits numBits)
```

Using Library functions with RSA:

```
import Control.Monad.Fix 
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes

rndPrime :: Int -> IO Integer
rndPrime bits =
    fix $ \again -> do
        x <- fmap (.|. 1) $ randomRIO (2^(bits - 1), 2^bits - 1)
        if isPrime x then return x else again

rndPrimes :: Int -> IO (Integer, Integer)
rndPrimes bits = do
    p <- rndPrime bits
    fix $ \again -> do
        q <- rndPrime bits
        if p /= q then return (p, q) else again
```

Thanks guys, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you clarify on the "number of bits" part?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For generating an odd random prime number of a specific bit size there is this de facto way of doing it, assuming a (usually probabilistic) primality test `isPrime`:

```
rndPrime :: Int -> IO Integer
rndPrime bits =
    fix $ \again -> do
        x <- fmap (.|. 1) $ randomRIO (2^(bits - 1), 2^bits - 1)
        if isPrime x then return x else again
```

For RSA:

```
rndPrimes :: Int -> IO (Integer, Integer)
rndPrimes bits = do
    p <- rndPrime bits
    fix $ \again -> do
        q <- rndPrime bits
        if p /= q then return (p, q) else again
```

You can find ready-made fast primality tests in the [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) package, including the current state of the art, the *Baillie PSW test*.  Then just import the `Math.NumberTheory.Primes` module and the code above should work out of the box.

Comment: @user805981 import `Control.Monad.Fix`

Comment: @PhilipJF `Couldn't match expected type `Integer'
                with actual type `(Integer, Integer)'
    Expected type: IO (Integer, Integer)
      Actual type: IO ((Integer, Integer), (Integer, Integer))
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      fix
      $ \ again
          -> do { q <- rndPrimes bits;
                  if p /= q then return ... else again }
    In the expression:
      do { p <- rndPrimes bits;
           fix $ \ again -> do { ... } }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
`

Comment: @user805981 Compiles without a problem here. What is the exact code you're trying to compile?

Comment: @user805981: You're calling `rndPrimes` instead of `rndPrime`.

Comment: @hammar `prime.hs:7:20: Not in scope: `.|.'

prime.hs:7:29: Not in scope: `randomRIO'`

I'm now able to compile the number library. And my formatting seems to be correct. What does this mean? My code for it is currently updated into the original post.

Comment: @user805981: `.|.` is from the `Data.Bits` module, and `randomRIO` from `System.Random`. You'll need to import those modules.

Comment: you should honestly be my professor instead xD. It works beautifully now. :)

Comment: The test `p /= q` should not be practically relevant for non-trivial bitsizes, as the likelihood to get the same primes here is roughly the same of accidentally randomly getting the DNSSEC root key, isn’t it?

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck mister. The prime numbers are appearing so frequently that you just can try to enumerate all numbers from a given start number and pick the first one that is prime.

The solution would be something like this

```
import System.Random

type Prime = Integer

isProbablyPrime :: Prime -> Bool
isProbablyPrime n = error "insert miller rabin here"

pickFirstFrom :: Integer -> Prime
pickFirstFrom n = head $ filter isProbablyPrime [n..]

numBits = 1024
constantStdGen = mkStdGen 1234567 -- a random number

randomByBits n = fst $ randomR (2^(n-1), 2^n-1) constantStdGen

answer = pickFirstFrom (randomByBits numBits)
```

Here `answer` will be as you specified in your comments. Note however that you have to modify this code to allow more than one constant seed!

Comment: hmmm... strange its giving me the following error 
`Couldn't match expected type `Integer'
                with actual type `(a0, StdGen)'
    In the return type of a call of `randomByBits'
    In the first argument of `pickFirstFrom', namely
      `(randomByBits numBits)'
    In the expression: pickFirstFrom (randomByBits numBits)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
`

Comment: @user805981 You need a `fst`, `randomByBits n = fst $ randomR ...`. Small mistake in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I'm getting the following issue now `Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `IO Bool'
    In the return type of a call of `isMillerRabinPrime'
    In the expression: isMillerRabinPrime n
    In an equation for `isProbablyPrime':
        isProbablyPrime n = isMillerRabinPrime n
Failed, modules loaded: none.`

Comment: Yea, your version is `:: Integer -> IO Bool` but mine is `:: Integer -> Bool`. Try to use `constantStdGen` in order to avoid the `IO` parts (in particular `newStdGen`).

Comment: @Tarrasch Even changing would not work for me. The boolean does not match the returned expression, I guess... This is what I got from it.
` Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `m0 a0'
    In the return type of a call of `return'
    In the expression: return True
    In an equation for `isMillerRabinPrime':
        isMillerRabinPrime n
          | n `elem` primesTo100 = return True
          | otherwise
          = do { let pn = ...
                     ....;
                 witns 100 n >>= try }
Failed, modules loaded: none.`